# CSS rendering differently under Windows 8.1

Tags: css

I've been developing a browser extension for a while and have experienced no CSS layout issues with it. I just recently deployed the extension to a larger market and have been receiving some bug reports indicating that a UI element is being bumped down and made invisible because of a 1px width difference with the element. All of the calculations are the same, but the resulting layout is different.

This seems really odd to me. Everyone is using the latest version of Google Chrome (v35) and the problem seems localized to Windows 8.1, although one user reports seeing it in Ubuntu 14.0.4, as well.

https://github.com/MeoMix/StreamusChromeExtension/issues/230

Is this a bug that I should be reporting somewhere? Is the operating system something I can detect from CSS/JavaScript?

Looking for more information on the matter, but Google isn't turning up much.

The actual CSS in my .less file is:

```
#left-base-pane {
    #playlist-title-region {
        width: calc(~"100% - 106px");
        ...
    }
}
```

but when deployed to some operating systems it needs to be `"- 107px"`

Here it is broken for a user at "- 106px": [image]

and here it is displaying A-OK for me on Windows 7 using the same browser / same browser version:
[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows 8 computer for testing? I'm on a mac and it seems to be working for me so I can't really test it. What I would do is compare a working and a non-working version and check the differences. For example are the two icons the same width? Is the parent the same width? etc. Also another way to fix it is to use position:absolute on the icons and box-sizing:border-box and width:100% on the search bar.

Comment: Hey, I don't have access to a Windows 8 machine currently. I agree that would be the proper way to debug this and I will spin up a VM in a while if necessary. I just wanted to confirm that there wasn't a known issue with rendering in Windows 8.

It sounds like border-box would be a proper fix for this. I'm not very familiar with that property (but I do understand it). I'll try to apply that.

Comment: Yea I try to avoid calc because you never know when it might render 1px out like in this case. It's not necessarily calcs fault it could be that something else is 1px different for some reason. Try using box-sizing:border-box, width:100%, and padding-left:(width of left icon)px and padding-right:(width of right icon) and the absolutely position the icons to the left and right. Let me know if you have any trouble.